# Variable inside a forloop in Python Django

Tags: python, django

am new to Python and Django.
I have a problem. i want to increment the value of **current** inside the for loop and check if the value is equal to **1** and if not i want to display some HTML tags.

**here is my code.**

```
{% with current=1 %}
{% for howitwork in howitworks%}
{% if current != 1 %}                     
<div class=item>
    <div class=container-fluid>
        <div class=row>
            <div class="col-md-5 rex-block">
                <img src="media/{{ howitwork.image }}" alt>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-7 rx-services-box">
                <div class=rx-conta-title>
                    <h3>{{ howitwork.subtitle }}</h3>
                </div>
                <p>{{ howitwork.description|linebreaks }}</p>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
{% endwith %}
```

I don't see any errors but its not working.

Comment: So what value of `current` do you see in the for loop?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you need to skip the logic on first loop iteration just use forloop.first field. It is accessible inside forloop block.

```
{% for howitwork in howitworks %}
{% if not forloop.first %}
<!-- do stuff -->
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: This is speculative answer!

Comment: @Rohan I've just assumed that he was using current variable to track current iteration (I used to do the same when I was a Django newbie), that's why I've answered this way.

Answer (score 3):

Use `forloop.counter` (`forloop.counter0` for 0-indexed) instead of current variable.

Here is the possible solution for your snippet:

```
{% for howitwork in howitworks%}
{{forloop.counter}}
{% if forloop.counter != 1 %}
<div class=item>
    <div class=container-fluid>
        <div class=row>
            <div class="col-md-5 rex-block">
                <img src="media/{{ howitwork.image }}" alt>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-7 rx-services-box">
                <div class=rx-conta-title>
                    <h3>{{ howitwork.subtitle }}</h3>
                </div>
                <p>{{ howitwork.description|linebreaks }}</p>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1):

To check the current iteration count, you can use `{{forloop.counter}}`

So your condition could be like this

```
{% if forloop.counter == 1 %}
   <!-- Do things -->
{% else %}
   <!-- Do some other things -->
{% endif %}
```